# Selecting a particular index cell value in multilevel Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Multilevel dataframe with following information:

```
A  B  123  1     value1      value2
      654  2     value3      value4
C  D  543  2     value1      value2
      999  2     value5      value7
```

I want to select for example only one value 123 or 654 or 543 etc (part of index) using the index values A and B ( or C and D) .
Values A, B, C, D are limited so can be easily searched against a list in a loop.
But values 123 or 654 or 543 can range from 0 to 20000 so using for loop to get it are making thing very slow.

Thank you. 
Providing more details:
I am trying to access dataframe df (created by you in answer) using loops.
df is a big dataframe.

enter code here

```
# Dataframe df1 have 2 columns with with subset of values in level0 and      #level1 of df1.
for index1 in range(len(df1)):
   for index2 in range(len(df1)):
        # x, y will fetch particular value of level0 & level1 respectively
        x = df1.loc[(index1),'level0column']
        y = df1.loc[(index2),'level1column']
        # Trying to get values for level2 values
        for level2ids in range(20000):
            for level3ids in range(2):
           total1 =  df.loc[(x,y, level2ids,level3ids), 'value_x']
           ......
```

Want to replace below line of code.

```
    # Trying to get values for level2 values

    for level2ids in range(20000):
```

Since df is a big dataframe and i am fetching values of level0 and level1 at runtime, I wanted to somehow want to fetch value of level2 also at run time. Fetching value of level2 for a particular value of level0 and level1  will give me only a list with very less values.
Wonder if it is possible or not and also wondering if i am to clarify my issue or not.

Comment: Hello, could you provide some more clarification? Are for example, are A, B,123 and 1 (in the first row) all a row index?

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'level0':['A','A','C','C'],
                   'level1':['B','B','D','D'],
                   'level2':[123,654,543,999],
                   'level3':[1,2,2,2],
                   'value_x':['value1','value3','value1','value5'],
                   'value_y':['value2','value4','value2','value7']})
# set the index
df.set_index(['level{}'.format(i) for i in range(4)], inplace=True)
```

which returns:

```
                                value_x value_y
level0  level1  level2  level3      
  A       B      123       1    value1  value2
                 654       2    value3  value4
  C       D      543       2    value1  value2
                 999       2    value5  value7
```

You should be able to use the mechanics of [label-based indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
df.loc[('A','B',123,1),:]
```

which returns:

```
value_x    value1
value_y    value2
Name: (A, B, 123, 1), dtype: object
```